# Check if developer options is enabled in React-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am developing a react-native web view app. For some reason, On Android. I don't want my users to allow inside the app if enable developer options are turned on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user just enters inside the application, you can check if the Developer Options is enabled or not.
[You can use "Jail Monkey" Library to do that.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jail-monkey)

After checking for Developer Options, you can display a pop up that you can't enter the application because developer options are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

When you are developing your app locally, it will be in a "development" build, which has the developer options enabled by default.

When you release your app to the public, not only will it have better performance, but the developer options will be disabled by default.

> The Developer Menu is disabled in release (production) builds.
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

To try it out yourself, you can [build a release version of your app](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#testing-the-release-build-of-your-app).

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

In short, you shouldn't have to worry about your users having access to the developer options.

Additionally, there is a [constant value](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment#specific) of `__DEV__` which will be `true` in development builds but `false` in release builds, you can also check it to toggle features based on environment.

Comment: The thing is,  I don't want to allow the users inside the app if the developer options in the mobile settings is turned on, It is because of some security issues like Geo Mock Enabling

Comment: Turning on the developer options in the mobile settings should not affect production/release builds of your app, only the ones you build for development.

As for geolocation mocking, it's generally safe to assume that your users will be able to fake the geolocation on your (or anyone else's) app, that doesn't require mocking it in the developer options.

Comment: You can't mock GPS without setting the Mock apps in the developer options.

Comment: How is this answering the question ?